# css selectror not working in selenium with python

Tags: python, css, selenium

I want to scroll to the end of a page till a particular type of element starts. I am able to select that element in Selenium ide but when used in python code, it is not selecting that element.

My Python code is:

```
while (True):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    current = len(WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_698"))))
    try:

        moreElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.element_located_to_be_selected((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._5vf:nth-child(2)")))
        print " more element is  " + moreElement
        break
    except:
        print " could not found  more ELEMENT "
```

In above code I want scrolling to end when element `div._5vf:nth-child(2))` is found.

Comment: Why you are going to scroll, if selenium itself  scroll to element and find that element if visible????

Comment: what is the actual behavior that you are seeing with your python code?  are there specific exceptions thrown?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i just want to  scroll friend list of a facebook account . in this case class name is _698 and when friend list ends then other elements starts scrolling because class name is also same for other list elements. So i want to stop scrolling when other elements appears. when i m finding other elements in selenium ide, in selenium ide it is blinking

Comment: @BreaksSoftware there is not exception thrown , but it keeps on scrolling even my desired elements completed and other elements start appearing

Comment: @SaurabhGaur please answer as i have been stuck with this problem for the last 3 days.

Comment: @vivek i think there is no need a while loop just find that element where you want to stop scroll and scroll to that particular element using  as `moreElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.element_located_to_be_selected((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._5vf:nth-child(2)")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", moreElement)`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur  Below is my full code. In code just enter facebook user name and password which i left blank and after running the program , enter any facebook id as input:  from selenium import webdriver

Comment: @SaurabhGaur  i m not able to paste my code as it is exceeding the character counts limit so plz give me email id so that i can sent it to u.

Comment: @vivek saurabh.gaur@bqurious.com

Comment: Are you attempting to automate facebook pages?  Why not use their API to get what you need?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i  have sent u my code on ur email id from my email id vivekgupta.android@rediffmail.com  .  Thank u for ur great coperation

Comment: @BreaksSoftware facebook api is providing very limited functionality.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur have u seen my code?